# prove that this equation has infinite solutions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to prove that this equation has infinite solutions and I don't really know how to do that.
$$
x^{\cos (x)} \left( \frac{\cos (x)}{x} - \sin (x) \ln (x) \right) = 0
$$

Comment: I guess it will be useful : consider the derivate of second multiplier. If you prove that there is a infinite changing of sign of first derivate and find some sequence of point , there second part has different signs , then you prove that there are infinity many solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can write out your expression as $$x^{\mathrm{cos}(x)}\cdot \left(-\mathrm{sin}(x)\cdot \log(x) + \cos(x)\cdot \frac{1}{x} \right)$$
and notice that the parentheses is a differential $$x^{\mathrm{cos}(x)}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left(\mathrm{cos}(x)\cdot \log(x)\right)$$
Notice that the function $$\mathrm{cos}(x)\cdot \log(x)$$
has differential equal to zero for every local maximum/minimum. Hence there are infinitely many solutions on $\mathbb{R}_+$, since our wave function induces these local maxima/minima.

Comment: I also noted that original expression is nothing but derivative of $x^{\cos(x)}$. But tell me how can you conclude about derivative from $\cos(x) \log(x)$ ? And how it is zero for $x = \pi k$ ???

Comment: oh I think that went too fast, and I'm wrong. My conclusion about infinite solutions stands. Simply put our wave function dictates that the strictly increasing logarithm will fluctuate up and down. So I just handwave and know the differential is 0 for every local maximum and minimum (of which there are infinitely many). Sorry about the rash conclusion of the solutions, I'll edit that out.

Comment: Now its more like it! Since $\cos(x) = 0$ for $(2k+1)\pi$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have infinitely many points of extrema. Good answer +1!

Comment: @mort as samjoe noted, the expression is the derivative of $x^{cos(x)}$, so the existence of infinitely many local maxima/minima of that function is enough.